# Why isn't my Pygame colliderect() working?

Tags: python, pygame

I am creating a game where the player moves around a grid and dodges rocks, but my code for detecting collision doesn't seem to work.

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import random

pygame.init()

xSize = 500
ySize = 500
win = pygame.display.set_mode((xSize, ySize), RESIZABLE)

pygame.display.set_caption('Grid Game: Featuring Sad Blue Circle')

grid = pygame.image.load('gr.png').convert()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

rockWait = 1000
rock_spawn_ev = pygame.USEREVENT

class player(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.right = [pygame.image.load('right_%s.png' % frame) for frame in range(1, 9)]
        self.x = 109
        self.y = 109
        self.frameCount = 0
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, 32, 32) #rect for collision

    def draw(self, win):
        if self.frameCount + 1 >= 40:
            self.frameCount = 0
        win.blit(self.right[self.frameCount//5], (self.x, self.y))
        self.frameCount +=1
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, 32, 32) #update rect position


class rock(object):

    def __init__(self, vel):
        self.rock = pygame.image.load('rock.png')
        self.vel = vel
        self.ran = random.randint(0, 3)
        self.ran2 = random.randint(1, 10) * 50 - 41
        if self.ran > 1:
            self.x = 550
            self.y = 550
        else:
            self.x = -50
            self.y = -50
        rocks.append(self)
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, 32, 32) #rect for collision

    def draw(self, win): 
        if self.ran == 0: #top to bottom
            self.y += self.vel
        win.blit(self.rock, (self.ran2, self.y))

        if self.ran == 2: #bottom to top
            self.y -= self.vel
        win.blit(self.rock, (self.ran2, self.y))

        if self.ran == 1: #left to right
            self.x += self.vel
        win.blit(self.rock, (self.x, self.ran2))

        if self.ran == 3: #right to left
            self.x -= self.vel
        win.blit(self.rock, (self.x, self.ran2))
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, 32, 32) #update rect position


def rgw():
    win.blit (grid, (0,0))
    player.draw(win)
    for rock in rocks:
        rock.draw(win)
        colliding = player.rect.colliderect(rock.rect)

        if colliding:
            print('collide') #nothing happens, even when touching rock
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.time.set_timer(rock_spawn_ev, rockWait)

player = player()

rocks = []

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(60)

    events = pygame.event.get()

    for event in events:
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        if event.type == rock_spawn_ev:
            rock(6)

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP and player.y > 9:
                player.y -= 50
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN and player.y < ySize - 41:
                player.y += 50
            elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT and player.x > 9:
                player.x -= 50
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT and player.x < xSize - 41:
                player.x += 50

    rgw()
pygame.quit()
```

I think that `colliding = player.rect.colliderect(rock.rect)` should return `True` when touching a rock, but `"collide"` never gets printed, in this for loop:

```
for rock in rocks:
        rock.draw(win)
        colliding = player.rect.colliderect(rock.rect)

        if colliding:
            print('collide') #nothing happens, even when touching rock
```

I know that the for loop itself works, because the rocks are being drawn

```
class player(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 109
        self.y = 109
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, 32, 32) #rect for collision

    def draw(self, win):
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, 32, 32) #update rect position


class rock(object):

    def __init__(self):
        rocks.append(self)
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, 32, 32) #rect for collision

    def draw(self, win): 
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, 32, 32) #update rect position

player = player()
rocks = []
def rgw():
    win.blit (grid, (0,0))
    player.draw(win)
    for rock in rocks:
        rock.draw(win)
        colliding = player.rect.colliderect(rock.rect)
        if colliding:
            print('collide') #nothing happens, even when touching rock
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Sorry if this is a silly question. I'm new to pygame.

Comment: It will help if you can make a [mre].

Comment: @khelwood Ok,  I made one

Comment: Your player image is 32x32 pixels right?  Normally you set the rect off the image:  `self.rect = self.image.get_rect()`.  If the rect has an incorrect size, this could cause your issue.  Maybe try drawing the collision rects too themselves (just the outline) when you paint the sprites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, there is no rock drawn at the position `(self.x, self.y)`, but there are rocks drawn at the positions `(self.ran2, self.y)` and `(self.x, self.ran2)`

---

I recommend to create the rectangles which surround the objects from the corresponding [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) objects. Use [`get_rect()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_rect) to generate a [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) object with the size of the image and set the position by keyword arguments (`self.rect = self.rock.get_rect(topleft = (self.x, self.ran2))`) or use the rectangle which is returned by [`pygame.Surface.blit`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit). For instance:

```py
class player(object):
    # [...]

    def draw(self, win):
        # [...]
        self.rect = win.blit(self.right[self.frameCount//5], (self.x, self.y))
```

```py
class rock(object):
    # [...]

    def draw(self, win): 
        # [...]
        self.rect = win.blit(self.rock, (self.x, self.ran2))
```

---

Since in the class `rock` are drawn 2 rocks at the positions `(self.ran2, self.y)` and `(self.x, self.ran2)`, you have to set 2 different rectangle objects:

```py
class rock(object):
    # [...]

    def draw(self, win): 
        # [...]

        self.rect_1 = win.blit(self.rock, (self.ran2, self.y))

        # [...]

        self.rect_2 = win.blit(self.rock, (self.x, self.ran2))
```

And you have to do 2 collision tests:

```py
def rgw():
    win.blit (grid, (0,0))
    player.draw(win)
    for rock in rocks:
        rock.draw(win)

        colliding = player.rect.colliderect(rock_1.rect) or player.rect.colliderect(rock_2.rect)
        if colliding:
            print('collide') #nothing happens, even when touching rock

    pygame.display.update()
```